# Cannot build a ferry terminal

Tags: simcity-2013

Why can't I build a [ferry terminal](http://simcity2013wiki.com/wiki/Ferry_Terminal) anywhere in the city?

It always says either "On top of road" (which it is) or "Must plop on snap point!!!" (everywhere else). This is very weird at least.

Comment: It would be useful if you included the name of the city in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ferry Terminals must be constructed not on a river shore, but on a shoreline accessing bigger waters.